# Google Cloud App to Database encrypted, private, or in need of protection?

Tags: sql-server, ssl, encryption, google-cloud-platform

I have a Google Cloud server with an app connecting to a SQL database. The database provides me with SSL options, that way I can encrypt my connection to the database. I do this when connecting from my Database to my personal computer, but **is it necessary to encrypt my app to database connection when they are both on the same project in Google Cloud?** Do we know what that relationship looks like? Would Google Cloud already encrypt it? Would it just be private? Or is it completely open, and in need of encryption?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer this question, you first need to build a 'threat model'. This means explicitly identifying what things you are trying to defend, and who you are trying to defend them against.  For the first you might think about the risk of data being stolen, fake data being inserted, deniel-of-service, money being stolen, extortion, user trust being lost, etc.  For the second, consider insider threats, criminals, governments, rival businesses, Google itself etc.

Once you have an idea of what threats you need to defend against and which you don't, then you can start figuring out what security steps are necessary to fulfil that.

In terms of Google Cloud Platform, here are some considerations:

- GCP does not allow other GCP customers to access the traffic between your GCP resources or between your GCP resources and traffic. So, baring a bug in GCP, you don't encryption to defend against that.
- Google itself probably is capable of looking at that traffic (at least in theory). If you see Google as a threat to defend against, you probably need encryption. However in this scenario you would also need to use Customer Supplied Encryption keys (as otherwise Google holds the encryption keys to your data on disk), and solve numer outher ways Google could access your data.
- Govenments potentially have the ability to tap Google's fiber between regions, and conceivably within a region. Encryption on the wire is valid to protect against that risk.

Comment: David, thanks for the response, but I think you're missing a key component of the question. What I want to know is, assuming my database must be secure, does the connection have to be encrypted. The reason it wouldn't have to be encrypted is that Google Cloud would be using a localhost connection to the server, and it wouldn't be possible for a hacker to intercept said signal. And I agree, it is a safe to assume Google could access it if they wanted to.

Comment: Traffic from GAE, GKE or GCE to a Cloud SQL instance or MySQL running on a different GCE instance is not encrypted as it travels over Google's network. However it _is_ isolated, so other customers cannot get access to it.

Comment: Connections between an app on one GCE instance and MySQL running on the same instance never leave the instance, so never touches the network (encrypted or unecrypted)

Comment: Traffic from outside Google to a Cloud SQL instance or MySQL on GCE does go across the public internet, so is visible to third parties unless encrypted.

Comment: So would I have any reason to encrypt it if it is isolated?

Comment: That's kind of what my main post was getting at: if you are defending against outsiders/criminals, probably not. if you need to defend against insiders to your organization, Google itself, governments, bugs in Google (which might break the isolation) then encryption does help.